# How to install Tomcat 7.0.42 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-installation, tomcat

The sysadmin gave me a virtual machine which I access through terminal.

I have root access and it got **Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS**.

The command `apt-cache policy tomcat7` informs:

```
tomcat7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     7.0.26-1ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
     7.0.26-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
root@mymachine:~#
```

However, I'd like to **install** the latest Tomcat 7 (7.0.42) on it.

Is it doable? If yes, how?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install Tomcat 7.0.42, but you'll have to do it "manually".Here are steps on how to do so:

> **Note**: visit this question if you want to know why it's not in the repositories: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)
>
> **Prerequisite**: you need to have Java installed, and we need its
>   path. Java is usually installed under `/usr/lib/jvm`. Once you have
>   installed Java, you can run the command `update-alternatives --config
>   java` to show you the exact path; look at the first entry (the one
>   with a `*` next to it. You can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit this
>   screen). We only need the directory after `/jvm/`. On my machine, the
>   directory was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/`. This answer will
>   assume that this is the Java directory, but you should change the
>   commands accordingly.

1. `wget http://mirror.atlanticmetro.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.42.tar.gz`

   - This will download Tomcat 7.0.42 to your current directory.
2. `tar xzvf apache-tomcat-7.0.42.tar.gz`

   - This will extract the files.
3. `sudo mv apache-tomcat-7.0.42 /usr/local`

   - This moves Tomcat to `/usr/local`. You can choose any path you want. The remaining commands will assume you have used this path.
4. `nano ~/.bashrc` - this will open up a text editor. Go to the end of the file (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) and add the following two lines:

   ```
   export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/
   ```

   > **Remember**: this was the path to my Java. Change it to your installed Java.
5. `. ~/.bashrc`

   - This will apply the changes we made.
6. `sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` - you should see something like  this:

   ```
   Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/temp
   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
   Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
   ```

   And no errors.

You're done. Point your browser to `http://localhost:8080` and you should see the Tomcat page:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the beautiful answer, thanks for the effort !

Comment: Exact explanation which a basic user can also follow. Nice Job.

Comment: This was such an amazing explanation. Couldn't make IntelliJ to work, now it is possible. You rock!